# Callback for find not working-Javascript

Tags: javascript, find, javascript-objects

I have written a custom callback function for Javascript's find function
but that is always yielding `undefined`

```js
var objectsArray = [
  { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 },
  { 'a': 41, 'b': 5, 'c': 7 },
  { 'a': 9, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 },
  { 'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 99 }
];

function mytestMatchesProp(inputKey,val){
    let matchFunc = function(element,index,array){
      Object.keys(element).every(function(key){
          let val1 = (key==inputKey) && (element[key] == val)
          return val1
      })
    }
    return matchFunc
}

let res = objectsArray.find(mytestMatchesProp('a',9))
 console.log('output',res)
```

I have added a running snippet, any suggestion would be helpful.
Maybe i am missing something minor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `every` to `some` for first, because the every will always return false and also return the result of `Object.keys(element).some...`. And can simplify.

But I can suggest you more simple code, you only need to check if the property is in the object and it's value is the `val`, with using `lambdas`

```js
var objectsArray = [
  { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 },
  { 'a': 41, 'b': 5, 'c': 7 },
  { 'a': 9, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 },
  { 'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 99 }
];

function mytestMatchesProp(inputKey,val){
    return (element,index,array) => inputKey in element && element[inputKey] === val;
}

let res = objectsArray.find(mytestMatchesProp('a',9))
 console.log('output',res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 4):

You could just return the function for the callback with the right check without key iteration.

```js
var objectsArray = [
  { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 },
  { 'a': 41, 'b': 5, 'c': 7 },
  { 'a': 9, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 },
  { 'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 99 }
];

function mytestMatchesProp(inputKey, val){
    return function(element, index, array){
        return inputKey in element && element[inputKey] === val;
    };
}

let res = objectsArray.find(mytestMatchesProp('a', 9));
console.log('output', res);
```